# Contacting mpdf project: SO is not the best place for their support questions

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

**Context**

While going through review queues, I noticed [this message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57585602/i-want-to-page-break-as-1st-image-with-mpdf), which is a legitimate support request for the [mpdf tool](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) but not a good question on SO.

When I went to the project to look for a better forum for that question, I found this text in their documentation:

> For general questions or troubleshooting please use the mpdf tag at Stack Overflow (and not the project's issue tracker).

I went back over the `mpdf` tag to see, and it looks like at least half of those questions typically go unanswered, without counting the deleted ones I cannot see anymore, so it seems like SO is not that effective for them.

**Question**

Is it considered acceptable use of SO for a project to point their users here for support?

**Suggestion**

Can an SO moderator or an SE employee contact them (maybe through a ticket on their [issues tracker](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues)) to let them know that SO is not working that well for their users, and that they should probably find a more appropriate channel for their support requests? Or at least that someone from their project should monitor that tag here and answer the questions that come up.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745 for acceptable usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems acceptable to me. mpdf is a programming library. As such, questions about how to use at are clearly capable of being on-topic on Stack Overflow.

The [specific question you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57585602/1709587) is somewhat unclearly written, and it took me a while to understand what was being asked. However, once I did, it's simple, well-specified problem. (Specifically: the asker is using mpdf to render a HTML table in a PDF. But when a table row doesn't fit at the bottom of a page, mpdf chooses to leave a blank space at the bottom of that page and drop the entire table row to the next page. The asker would like to instead split the table row over the two pages, and is asking how to do that.) That's a programming problem, specified well enough to be answerable. It could do with an edit to make it clearer, and could also do with some simple example code that demonstrates the undesirable behaviour that the asker wants to change, but it's otherwise on-topic here.

I don't see any reason to reach out to the mpdf development team. They're not doing anything wrong by directing their users here.

Comment: If they aren't here to answer those questions then that is a poor reflection on them.

Comment: Even if the question might be on-topic, it is certainly missing all details. What's the input html code, how is the library used, ...

Comment: @ChrisF Disagree. There are over 1000 questions about mpdf here - a library that [has *one* active maintainer, finwe](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/graphs/contributors). He fixes issues and reviews and merges PRs and has put up [extensive documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/). He's not morally obligated to *also* answer 1000 questions on Stack Overflow, as the price of making a piece of software available to the world. Let him do the bits of work that he's willing to take on, and whoever wishes to do so shoulder the rest.

Comment: @MarkAmery - I wasn't aware that it was just one person. The usual state of affairs is for companies to tell people to use SO and not follow up. However, I still believe it would look better if they were clear that they can't handle all the questions themselves.

Comment: @MarkAmery thank you for the clear answer and clarification about the mpdf project and its author. I'm a lot more willing to consider good questions from that project in the circumstances you describe.